How to develop a .NET Web API for Response Handling with Machine Learning, where the model Trained on Google Colab?
I've been exploring options to train a machine learning model in Google Colab and deploy it as part of a .NET web API to handle incoming requests. While there are plenty of resources available for training models in Google Colab and deploying them in Python-based environments, I couldn't find much information on integrating machine learning models trained in Colab with a .NET web API.
Here's what I want:

Train a machine learning model using Google Colab using
libraries like TensorFlow or PyTorch.
Export the trained model in a format compatible with .NET
applications.
Develop a .NET web API using ASP.NET Core to handle incoming
requests.
Load the exported model within the .NET environment and use it to
generate responses to incoming requests.

